# Instantiating UIViewController Without A Storyboard Or xib File

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization, xcode6, nscoder

I have been looking for a a way to instantiate a custom UIViewController class which is not attached to a storyboard or xib file.

Naturally, when I try to initialize the UIViewController it's expecting an NSCoder object.

However I have no idea where this NSCoder object comes from or how to properly make it. The documentation says its an interface declaration object.

Do you know how I can make an NSCoder object that will let me initialize my UIViewController or is there an NSCoder object somewhere in the application I can fetch?

```
public class Controller:UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate
{
    var _viewAuto:AutoUI! //newName

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is only ever called when a view is instantiated from a storyboard. To create a custom UIViewController and instantiate in manually, all you need to do is add:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

to your custom view controller. Now you're free to create your own initialization method and pass it whatever variables you like.

Comment: I have this and it still wont let me init it without a coder.

Comment: I updated my question with my code, and when I try to instantiate a UIViewController. It wont let me init it without the coder still. I cant just use ()

Comment: That's odd. Can you post the code from class where the initializing is happening? I'm assuming C_NewPhotoEditor is a Controller--on a sidenote, UIAlertViewDelegate is deprecated as of IOS8, so you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: The init is the same as the Controller, its just a subclass with the same empty init call.

Comment: I mean what is the type of C_NewPhotoEditor? I just compiled your code without any errors or warning, so C_NewPhotoEditor must not conform in some way to your example there. Are you sure C_NewPhotoEditor's type isn't just a UIViewController?

Comment: Controller is a subsclass of UIViewController, as is C_NewPhotoEditor

Comment: Ive added the class signature

Comment: Did you override init() in C_NewPhotoEditor, too?

Comment: Yes I had added     required public override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeVars()
    }

Comment: When I removed this it worked, thank you. I am moving away from storyboards and it seems this (legacy code) was forcing it to still required a coder